# Running a cmd .bat file with loops and conditions

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, scrapy

Hi I am trying to run a scrapy spider using start command from a cmd batch file. I want to run the spider parallely for 10 names from a csv file which contains more than 500 names. So my thought is to basically add some conditions in the loop from 1 to 500 that checks if the 10 command windows have closed, if not then wait for them to close (they auto close after spider is finished). Once the 10 windows which had opened, are closed, open the next 10 and so on. Following is the code I have, i am pretty sure it has big syntax errors. Could you help me debug? Thanks

```
cd /d "C:\Users\xyz"
for /f "tokens=1,*" %%m in ('tasklist ^| find /I /C "conhost.exe"') do (set var1=%%m)
set counter=1
for /f "usebackq tokens=1 delims=," %%n in ("test.csv") do (
    (START /MIN "" scrapy crawl xyz_scraper -a query="%%n" -a pages=20) 
    set /a counter=counter+1
    for /f "tokens=1,*" %%p in ('tasklist ^| find /I /C "conhost.exe"') do (set var2=%%p)
    SET /A _result=counter%%10
    echo %_result% 
    IF _result EQU 0 (
        :abcd 
        timeout /t 10
        if var2 EQU var1 (
            goto bcde
            ) 
            ELSE (
            goto abcd)
        )
    :bcde
    )
pause
```

EDIT: deleted the for loop one. Edited the above code based on some suggestions. I don't understand where would i use quotes for variables and where not and how to print a variables value to cmd.

The updated code below:

```
    cd /d "C:\Users\sodhian\sodhi-scraper"
    for /f "tokens=1,*" %%m in ('tasklist ^| find /I /C "conhost.exe"') do (set var1=%%m)
    echo %var1%
    set counter=1
    for /f "usebackq tokens=1 delims=," %%n in ("test comp.csv") do (
        (START /MIN "" scrapy crawl ind_scraper -a query="%%n" -a pages=20) 
        set /a "counter=counter+1"
        echo %counter%
        SET /A _result="counter%%2"
        echo %_result%
        IF "%_result%" EQU "0" (
            :abcd 
            timeout /t 10
            for /f "tokens=1,*" %%p in ('tasklist ^| find /I /C "conhost.exe"') do (set var2=%%p)
            echo %var2%
            if var2==var1 (
                goto bcde
                ) 
                ELSE (
                goto abcd)
            )
        :bcde
        )
    pause
```

Edit 2:
Based on Stephan's answer. Tried to accomplish what i mentioned in comment of the answer:

```
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

    set counter=0
    for /f "usebackq tokens=1 delims=," %%n in ("test comp.csv") do (
      set /a counter+=1
      start /MIN "MySpider!counter!" scrapy crawl ind_scraper -a query="%%n" -a pages=20
      for /f "tokens=1,*" %%b in ('tasklist /v ^| find /I /C "MySpider"') do (set var1=%%b)
      if !var1! geq 5 call :wait
    )
    :wait
    timeout /t 5
    for /f "tokens=1,*" %%p in ('tasklist /v ^| find /I /C "MySpider"') do (set var2=%%p)
    if !var2! geq 5 call :wait
    goto :eof
```

Changed it to the following: (the /v (verbose option in tasklist was making the above slow)

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set counter=0
set max_scrappers=7
for /f "tokens=1,*" %%a in ('tasklist ^| find /C "conhost"') do (set var1=%%a)
for /f "usebackq tokens=1 delims=," %%n in ("test comp.csv") do (
    set /a counter+=1   
    start /min "MySpider!counter!" scrapy crawl ind_scraper -a query="%%n" -a pages=20
    for /f "tokens=1,*" %%b in ('tasklist ^| find /C "conhost"') do (set var2=%%b)
    set /a var3=!var2!-!var1!
    if !var3! geq !max_scrappers! call :wait
)
:wait
for /f "tokens=1,*" %%p in ('tasklist ^| find /C "conhost"') do (set var4=%%p)
set /a var5=!var4!-!var1!
if !var5! geq !max_scrappers! call :wait
goto :eof
```

Comment: I wouldn't use `.bat` if I can do it with python.

Comment: Set a common title with the `START` command and count those instead.

Comment: This is incorrect: `IF _result EQU 0`.  Variables need to be resolved using percent symbols or exclamation marks.  In your case you need to use delayed expansion and exclamation marks because you are inside a parenthesized code block.

Comment: This is not even remotely close to a valid command in a batch file: `for var1 NEQ var2 do`.

Comment: labels within code blocks (parenthesised sequences of lines) are essentially not allowed.

Comment: @Squashman Thanks a lot for your reply. If possible, could you help me in formulating the answer. 
I didnt understand your first comment regarding common title.
For second comment are you saying something like IF  %_result% EQU 0 ..... ?
For your third comment i used the For condition from this page - but now that I am looking at it again it seems wrong. So i'll stick with the first code instead. 
Thanks for your help, this is the first time I am using batch scripting.

Comment: @Magoo you means lables such as :abcd is not valid?. Thanks

Comment: @furas so your suggestion is to invoke cmd prompt from within python?

Comment: Certainly. Also you need to find out about `delayed expansion` (there are many, many examples on SO - use `search` in the top bar) where a variable is `set` within a `code block`. Also `for ... neq ... ` is nonsense.

Comment: I suggest that you can do all `for/if` with Python and scrapy has methods to run spiders in other python script. See in documentation: [Run Scrapy from a script](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html). If you have program in script which you  can't replace with Pythone then you can use `subprocess` to run it. See [tasklist wrapper](https://gist.github.com/intco/6149781)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already noted in the comments, labels inside a code block don't work. But you can call a "function", where `goto` and labels are no problem:

I choosed other numbers and another command to make it work on every system (and faster). Replacing the `timeout` command with your spider and adapting the numbers should be no problem.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

REM next line just for generating a testfile:
>"test comp.csv" (for /l %%i in (1,1,10) do echo !random:~-1!)

set counter=0
for /f "usebackq tokens=1 delims=," %%n in ("test comp.csv") do (
  set /a counter+=1
  start "MySpider!counter!" timeout %%n
  if !counter! geq 3 call :wait
)
:wait
tasklist /v|find "MySpider">nul && goto :wait
set counter=0
goto :eof
```

Searching for `conhost` is not a good idea, because there could be other processes. Choose an unique window title instead (`MySpider` in my example) and look for that title (`tasklist /v`)

Comment: Thank you so much. This was exactly what I was looking for. I modified the start "MySpider!counter!" timeout %%n
to;
start "MySpider!counter!" /min scrapy crawl ind_scraper -a query="%%n" -a pages=20
and removed the csv creation line obviously and it runs perfectly!

Comment: Hi @Stephan, one more question. What changes do I make to above if I want a new window to open as soon as one closes (so that at all times there are 3 windows open - instead of waiting for 3 to close and then opening new three). Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I have made some changes, and it is atleast running now but is slow, could you check the code once. Thanks

Comment: edit: if i change the timeout to 1 it improves speed.  Thanks